# Difference between 'normal shutdown' and shutdown via shell (shutdown -s)

Tags: windows-10

I'm wondering what difference there is if I shutdown Windows 10 via the 'usual' way, hence, `start->shut down` down or if I execute the `shutdown -s` (-t 0) command. I observed, that I can't write-access the HDD under another OS (e.g. Ubuntu) if I shutdown via `start->shut down` but I can write-access them when I use the `shutdown -s` command. Is there a way that I get this behaviour also via the usual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shutdown -s` command disables Fast Startup, while the Start Menu method does
Fast Startup.

You may disable Fast Startup for the normal shutdown to work the same way:

- Run *Start > Power Options*
- Click "Choose what the power buttons do"
- Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable"
- Click "Choose what the power buttons do"
- Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable"
- Click "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" so that the checkmark disappears
- Click Save changes.

[image]