What's the difference between start menu shutdown and shutdown command in Windows 10? (fast startup disabled)
OS is Windows 10 22H2 (19045.5011). Fast startup is already disabled (Can verify by looking at system up time). Local account bind with Microsoft account. Uses local account password to sign in (no Windows Hello). Not in AD.
I run a script every night that times the shutdown of my laptop (shutdown /s /t <sec>). And I noticed one strange behavior that is different from clicking the "Shut down" button in the start menu: It's not about the shutdown process, but the next sign-in would be a bit different, specifically:

If I used the shutdown command, the next sign-in will be a little bit longer. When enabled Verbose Status Messages, upon submitting the password, it will tell me to "Please wait for the Local Session Manager" and "Preparing Windows" before going into Desktop. This takes about 5 seconds. And then all startup programs begins to start when I got into Desktop. Pretty standard.
If I used the "Shut down" button in the start menu, the next sign-in will be super fast. With VSM enabled, upon submitting the password, it just simply tells me "Welcome" for about 300ms and puts me into Desktop with all startup programs already started. It looks like Windows does the preparation in advance while still in lock screen in this case.

This got me thinking: What's the difference between the two?

EDIT: The difference in behavior might be related to a Windows feature that is not fast startup.
I stumbled upon this question and this answer stated that there's this automatic setup feature. I disabled it and now using start menu shutdown and shutdown command is totally the same now.
But I do want this automatic setup to work even if I used shutdown command.
So this feature is:
Settings->Accounts->Sign-in Options->Privacy->"Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up after an update or restart"
and I quote:

If turned on, Windows uses your sign-in information to automatically complete the setup of your device and reopen your apps after an update. This option is designed to speed up the sign-in process and ensure that your device is locked afterward to help keep your account and personal information safe.

that will automatically prepare the system (like starting startup programs, opening previous Windows explorer windows etc.) while user is still at the lock screen after booting up so sign-ins will be very fast. Although it says "after an update or restart", it also works when I shutdown the system using the start menu shutdown button and start the system again.
If I shutdown the system with the shutdown command, the automatic setup feature does not work on next boot up.
Why is it different? What's the difference between these two shutdown methods?

EDIT of EDIT:
I solved my problem.
>shutdown /?
...
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /sg        Shutdown the computer. On the next boot, if Automatic Restart Sign-On
               is enabled, automatically sign in and lock last interactive user.
               After sign in, restart any registered applications.
...

The /sg argument will keep the automatic setup feature working.
So I guess the question is now more like about the real difference between start menu shutdown and shutdown command. Does start menu shutdown routine also invoke shutdown /sg command?

You should check your Fast Startup settings: https://superuser.com/questions/1634241/difference-between-normal-shutdown-and-shutdown-via-shell-shutdown-s

@music2myear Thank you for searching but please read my questions, fast startup is disabled in my system. Have made edits to further highlight this point.

While you state that Fast Startup is disabled, the evidence indicates that it is not, in fact, disabled. Can you share what it is about the system up time that indicates it is disabled? Also, Windows has a habit of ignoring certain things from time to time, sometimes by accident, sometimes as part of a planned, but unadvertised change. I wouldn't be surprised if you have set the setting to disable Fast Startup but it's still working. You've highlighted things, but please forgive my bluntness: We need evidence. The evidence we have says its still enabled.

Hi @music2myear thank you for responding. From my experience with fast startup, it doesn't reset the system up time (the one in task manager), so the up time continues to count on next system start up. If it's a real shutdown the system up time will reset.
Maybe you're right about Windows ignoring settings so I will do some more testing with my PC later, enable it and disable it again perhaps.

@Victor - Instead of commenting, edit your question, of course your question was already closed as a duplicate

Don't post a new one. You've already got the bones of a good question here, and now you've also proven fast startup is not at play here. This question should be reopened shortly with your edits.

@music2myear thanks. But I sort of answered my own question now. Though it would be great to reopen this question and hope we can find out the real difference between these two methods.

Yea, I voted to reopen. Over the course of the day other community members should add on and I would guess this question has a good chance of being reopened. Answering your own Qs is a good thing too, and is encouraged.
